# Wix DTF Custom Action Equivalent of WcaAddTempRecord

Tags: wix, dtf

I am trying to use Wix DTF custom action to write MSI runtime session values to registry.
This i wanted to achieve by adding temporary record to "Registry" table in the database.
Since c++ had a `WcaAddTempRecord` method to achieve this, really wanted to know is there any equivalent method in DTF.

Note: I tried using `Session.Database.OpenView` to insert the record, but consistently i am getting update failed error, due to session database readonly property.

Can someone please suggest the best approach for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The MSI database is read-only during the installation. So you cannot add permanent rows. However, you can insert temporary rows. Once you get the `View` back from the `Session.Database.OpenView()` then use the `InsertTemporary()` method on the `View` object to add temporary rows.

That's how `WcaAddTempRecord()` gets the **Temp** in its name. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my "go to" helper method:

```
private static void InsertTempRecord(Session session, string tableName, Object[] objects)
{
  Database db = session.Database; 
  string sqlInsertSring = db.Tables[tableName].SqlInsertString + " TEMPORARY";
  session.Log("SqlInsertString is {0}", sqlInsertSring);
  View view = db.OpenView(sqlInsertSring); 
  view.Execute(new Record(objects)); 
  view.Close(); 
}
```

For more information see:

[Dynamic Windows Installer UI](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/07/dynamic-windows-installer-ui.html)

Comment: I tried using above method but i am getting Table Update failed error. When i added InsertTemporary just before the view execute as below   View view = db.OpenView(sqlInsertSring);
            view.InsertTemporary(new Record(6));
            view.Execute(new Record(objects)); i get Database: . Cursor in invalid state and unable to proceed.

Comment: Does the table exist? WiX has a tendency to drop out unused tables when it builds an MSI.  You can use the EnsureTable element to instruct it not to do this. Are you sure you are passing in the correct number and types of objects?  I've used this method in a number of installs and there is no doubt in my mind that it works.

Comment: Updated answer to refer to a blog article I once wrote.  Wow, was it really 5 years ago?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, was a really silly mistake duplicate primary key. Worked like a charm

Comment: Yes i do accept the answer and fully acknowledge this as fully working piece of code. Kudos to Chris and Rob :)